# Take a new Windows7 computer and turn it to an internet server

Tags: asp.net, windows-7, iis-7, installation

Please go easy on me.

I was just given the task to take a new Windows7 computer and turn it to an internet server for an ASP.Net SQL Server 2012 database system.

We will be using IIS7 as the internet server.

I can install the IIS7 and SQL Server but we don't know how to proceed from that point onwards.

Can you point me in the right direction on where I can get step by step instructions on making this machine ready to be an internet server? We will also be looking for instructions on how to publish the completed ASP.Net application.

Comment: going to be closed in 0.03 seconds

Comment: @Артём Царионов we really need your help. I know this question is a bit on the vague side but we really don't where to start and they need this project finished as soon as possible. Please restore my reputation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after you deploy your site on iis

1. first check it can be accessed on local network like 192.168.1.2 (your local ip) on other computer with same shared network connection.
2. then go to router settings and add ip forwarding (under advance settings ) like 192.168.1.2 http
3. unblock any firewall
4. check your site via your router ip ( http://www.whatsmyip.org/)

if your service provider doesn't support static ip you can use http://dyn.com/dns/webhop/ for domain to ip forwarding (this will change domain attached ip when your system ip change).

Comment: thanks for such a quick reply and your much needed help. :-) We will use the info you just outlined.